# How to use a web browser for authorizing a WPF desktop application

Tags: wpf, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, desktop-application

Our custom Identity Provider (IdP) implements the OpenID Connect (OIDC) standards.
Many of our browser-based single-page applications use it for single sign-on (SSO) authentication/authorization.
Some of our desktop applications are based on Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).

Now, our requirement is to implement this same method by launching a browser from the desktop application, and then once the single sign-on is complete, come back to the desktop application.

This is very similar to how a Docker desktop does it – launching a browser for sign-in and then redirecting back to the desktop application.

What is the right way to implement this?

Any reference to an implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system browser is used to login, according to [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.1). I believe Docker desktop uses a private URI schene to receive the OAuth response.

See these resources. My app is coded in Javascript but you should be able to translate the concepts:

- [C# private URI scheme example](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/WindowsConsoleSystemBrowser)
- [My desktop code sample + blog posts](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final)

Comment: Thanks much @Gary Archer. This was very useful information to understand how OIDC/OAuth works for Native apps.